# Blank page on OpenShift-hosted site

Tags: openshift

I have site hosted on OpenShift with two pages. The main page works fine- loads right up. The second page, however, comes up totally blank. All of the sources are missing when I use Chrome's Inspect Element tool.  The html file is blank and the additional subdirectories (js, css, etc) are just gone.

I'm not getting any errors in the log beyond a "js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version" that I can't figure out but doesn't appear relevant.

The page worked fine for a while but started occurring today when I tried to change the content.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Have you tried to ssh to your app in see if sources are properly deployed? `rhc ssh <your_app_name>`

Comment: @AlexP What should I be looking for? Tail doesn't tell me much as mentioned and "gear deployments" (closest verbiage I could find to your comment) doesn't look like much either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't committed the latest version of your files to your OpenShift git repository. You need to make sure to perform a `git commit` before doing a `git push`

If that isn't the problem, use the `rhc ssh` command [detailed here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html) to log into your application gear and see what files exist there. That may give you some clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: With rhc ssh, I found /app-root/runtime/repo where there is a copy of my up-to-date html.

Comment: Have you configured hot deployments for your application? Have you tried manually restarting your application? Have you tried making another change to your application and redeploying?

Comment: I added hot deployments, retried manually restarting and retried making a different change and redeploying. No luck with any of them.